# Как перемещать абсолютно спозиционированные блоки?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, position

Как переместить абсолютно спозициориванный блок в другое место? К примеру если

`example {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 10px;
}`

и если я пытаюсь его переместить в другое место

`example {
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
}`

то у меня не получается так как почему то свойство top не сбрасывается и вроде бы bottom 0 но обьект все равно сверху. Почему оно так себя ведет и как быть с этим?

Comment: top: auto; bottom: 0;

Comment: Используйте проценты. Не `bottom: 0;`, а `top: 100%;`

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, это разные вещи

Comment: Ну для начала нужно добавить position: relative родителю.

Comment: @soledar10 Благодарю за помощь, можете сделать ответом укажу вас ответившим правильно если есть желание.

Comment: @НазарКалитюк Какое вообще отношение имеет ваш комментарий к моему вопросу? Это влияет лишь на то относительно чего будет позиционироваться элемент.

Comment: Не так понял вопрос. Все элементы располагаются по координатам начиная с левого верхнего угла. Поэтому, если у элемента есть одновременно свойства top и bottom или right и left, то в приоритете будут top и left для избежания конфликта. Можно отменить свойство при перемещении указав top: unset;